# Extraer columnas y celdas con un texto especifico en python

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Tengo varios archivos xls con multiples hojas en donde quiero que me indique la columna y celda de un texto 'Latitude'. Ya tengo un bucle para leer cada archivo y cada hoja en un Dataframe. sin embargo no encuentro la manera de recorer el dataframe hasta que encuentre la palabra 'Latitude'

````
import glob
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter as wr
folder=("D:\SCRIPT\xlsx")
files=glob.glob(folder+"/*.xlsx")

Fls= len(files) #number of files

for files in files:
    xls=files
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(files)
    sheet = wb.sheetnames
    df=pd.read_excel(xls,sheet_name=sheet)
    print df```

#output 
[53 rows x 11 columns]), (u'0353',     Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  ... Unnamed: 9 Unnamed: 10
0          NaN         NaN  ...        NaN         NaN
1          NaN         NaN  ...  Latitude      Altitud
2          NaN         NaN  ...     grados           m
3          NaN         NaN  ...    4.79494     2558.84
4          NaN         NaN  ...    4.79493     2558.85
5          NaN         NaN  ...    4.79493     2558.85
6          NaN         NaN  ...    4.79493     2558.87
7          NaN         NaN  ...    4.79493     2558.89
````

Answer (score 0):

Puedes iterar sobre las columnas y usar `pandas.Series.str.eq` o `pandas.Series.str.contain` para buscar aquellas celdas de la columna que tiene la cadena:

```
import glob
import os

import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils import cell 


folder = "D:/SCRIPT/xlsx"
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "*.xlsx"))

for file in files:
    dfs = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None, header=None)
    print("\nAnalizando ", file)
    for sheet, df in dfs.items():
        for col in df.select_dtypes(include=["object"]):
            for row_index, row in enumerate(df[col].eq('Latitude')):
                if row:
                    col_index = df.columns.get_loc(col)
                    print(("  Encontrada celda en {} -> fila: {}, columna: {}" 
                          .format(sheet, row_index, col_index)))
                    print("    Indices excel -> fila: {}, columna: {}".format(
                        row_index + 1, cell.get_column_letter(col_index)))
```

Ten en cuenta que puedes leer todas las hojas de un archivo si le pasas `None` al argumento `sheet_name` de `read_excel`. En este caso no considero la primera fila del Excel como cabeceras `header=None`, si lo son y no vas a buscar en ella dejalo con el valor por defecto simplemente.